# firefox causing float issue

Tags: html, css, firefox

Just finished building a site for an organization I'm in using wordpress. Built and tested using Chrome/Safari. I go to make sure everything is normal in Firefox and looks like my menu on the right side of the header is breaking to a new line in firefox and not in others.

I've tried debugging using firefox but haven't gotten very far with it. I'm suspecting it is the way the menu is floating, but I'm not sure.

Here is a link to a page of the site: http://www.ucmdeca.org/about/

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is giving you a more accurate result there. You are better off floating the logo too:

```
.homelink {float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file `style.css` try to change the trigger.

```
.mobile-trigger-button img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px; 
}
```

[image]